# Accessing multidimensional Array element by vector of it's positon

Tags: r

I'm looking for solution of following problem in R:

I want to create algorithm that will be able to operate on multidimensional array - where the number of dimension is input of algorithm.

In consequence, I would like to access some elements of such array using vectors.

In example:

```
> x = array(1:8, replicate(3,2))
> x
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

> x[1,2,2]
[1] 7
```

I would like to replace the line

```
x[1,2,2]
```

With something that will use

```
y = c(1,2,2)
```

Instead of hardcoded position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also index by matrix. This means that you can do

```
x[t(y)]
# [1] 7
```

This does have a different behavior if you are indexing by range however. I'm not in what context you are building the index so it's hard to say exactly what would be best for your situation.

Comment: This answer my question. Thanks. But why is matrix indexing allowed and vector indexing isn't?

Comment: Well, vector indexing *is* allowed, it just behaves differently. It's still unclear to me exactly what your indexing requirements are.

Comment: I think I get it now. Vector indexing selects elements from "linearized array". If we want to select element by it coordiants we have to use matrix and each row of matrix is one element to be selected. That why single line matrix created by `t(y)` works as single element select. Is that right? http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Array-indexing . Thanks for clarification btw :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
do.call(`[`, c(list(x), as.list(y)))
# [1] 7
```

`do.call` allows you to call any function with the parameters provided as a list.  Look at what `c(list(x), as.list(y))` looks like to get a sense of what's going on.