# Accessing n-dimensional array in R using a function of vector of indexes

Tags: arrays, r, n-dimensional

my program in R creates an n-dimensional array.

```
PVALUES = array(0, dim=dimensions)
```

where `dimensions = c(x,y,z, ... )`

The dimensions will depend on a particular input. So, I want to create a general-purpose code that will:

1. Store a particular element in the array
2. Read a particular element from the array

From reading this site I learned how to do #2 - read an element from the array

```
ll=list(x,y,z, ...)
element_xyz = do.call(`[`, c(list(PVALUES), ll))
```

Please help me solving #1, that is storing an element to the n-dimensional array.

---

Let me rephrase my question

Suppose I have a 4-dimensional array. I can store a value and read a value from this array:

```
PVALUES[1,1,1,1] = 43 #set a value
data = PVALUES[1,1,1,1] #use a value
```

How can I perform the same operations using a function of a vector of indexes:

```
indexes = c(1,1,1,1)
set(PVALUES, indexes) = 43
data = get(PVALUES, indexes) ?
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you mean `PVALUES[1][1][1][1]`? Don't you mean `PVALUES[1,1,1,1]`? Are you just setting one value at a time? Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807669/accessing-multidimensional-array-element-by-vector-of-its-positon/26809897#26809897)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for helpful response.

I will use the following solution:

```
PVALUES = array(0, dim=dimensions) #Create an n-dimensional array
dimensions = c(x,y,z,...,n)
```

Set a value to PVALUES[x,y,z,...,n]:

```
y=c(x,y,z,...,n)
PVALUES[t(y)]=26
```

Reading a value from PVALUES[x,y,z,...,n]:

```
y=c(x,y,z,...,n)
data=PVALUES[t(y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexing of arrays can be done with  matrices having the same number of columns as there are dimensions:

```
  # Assignment with "[<-"
  newvals <- matrix( c( x,y,z,vals), ncol=4)     
  PVALUES[ newvals[ ,-4] ]  <- vals

 # Reading values with "["
 PVALUES[ newvals[ ,-4] ]
```